# Elasticity of demand given a quantity and a price function

Tags: calculus, economics

I have a price function:
$$
\frac{8,100,000}{q^2+8,100}
$$

Where $q$ is quantity demanded.

How can I find the price elasticity when $q = 30$?

I know how to differentiate, but I'm just not sure what to differentiate... I'm used to having a demand function, not a price one.

eg:
$$
\frac{\%\text{ change in quantity}}{\%\text{ change in price}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The elasticity of demand is given by (dQ / dP)*(P/Q), where P is the price function and Q the demand. so you basically need the derivative of Q (at q=30) (with respect to P) multiplied by P/Q (at q=30). You have given your price as a function of quantity, but for this derivative, you will need it the other way around!

I'll leave the differentiation and algebra to you ;)!

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the derivative of Q without a function for Q, I only have a function for P and some initial quantities to solve for.

Comment: Because for an infinity small change in the number 30, the number 30 does not change. Thus it would be dq = 0 but that does not make sense.

Comment: What about f(q) / q * 1/ f'(q) ?

Comment: Whoops, I made a silly mistake in my answer - lolololol - I misread something. I will edit it - my bad.

Comment: Does that make sense now?

Comment: This is why I have this: f(q) / q * 1/ f'(q)

By doing that, I do not need the function for quantity.

Comment: I suggest using $p=8,100,000/(q^2 +8,100)$ and solve for q in terms of p, and then take the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

$P=\frac{8,100,000}{q^2+8100}$

$(q^2+8100)=\frac{8,100,000}{p}$

...

$q=...$

$\frac{dq}{dp}=...$

evaluate the appropriate quantities at the appropriate value and solve.